# ANTLR3 inject an int into my tree

Tags: antlr3, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to do what I'm attempting here?  Or, perhaps I'm approaching it wrong?

```
arrayDef
  : { int c = 0; }
    ('['']' {c++;})+
  -> ARRAY /* somehow inject c here */
  ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the `ChildCount` of your `ARRAY` tree node?

```
arrayDef
    :   ('[' ']')+
        -> ^(ARRAY '['+)
    ;
```